# Why is my GDB executing two breakpoints at a time?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am learning to use GDB to debug the following problematic C program:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2020, Dive into Systems, LLC (https://diveintosystems.org/)
 * Program with some bugs in the findAndReturnMax function
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/***************************************
 * this function should find the largest element in the array and
 * "return" it through max
 *  array: array of integer values
 *  len: size of the array
 *  max: set to the largest value in the array
 *      returns: 0 on success and non-zero on an error
 */
int findAndReturnMax(int *array1, int len, int max) {

    int i;

    if (!array1 || (len <=0) ) {
        return -1;
    }
    max = array1[0];
    for (i=1; i <= len; i++) {
        if (max < array1[i]) {
            max = array1[i];
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

/***************************************/
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int arr[5] = { 17, 21, 44, 2, 60 };

    int max = arr[0];

    if ( findAndReturnMax(arr, 5, max) != 0 ) {
        printf("strange error\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("max value in the array is %d\n", max);

    return 0;
}
```

I set a breakpoint at line 27, then execute it with the cont command and print the value of i. Why does the result seem to execute two breakpoints at a time? That is to say,The values of i that are printed are 1,2,4 instead of 1,2,3,4,5.

```
tetyang@tet:~/clash/clash/learn_c$ gdb badprog 

(gdb) break 27
Breakpoint 1 at 0x11fc: file badprog.c, line 27.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/tetyang/clash/clash/learn_c/badprog 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Breakpoint 1, findAndReturnMax (array1=0x7fffffffdb30, len=5, max=17) at badprog.c:27
27              max = array1[i];
(gdb) print i
$1 = 1
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, findAndReturnMax (array1=0x7fffffffdb30, len=5, max=21) at badprog.c:27
27              max = array1[i];
(gdb) print i
$2 = 2
(gdb) cont
Continuing.

Breakpoint 1, findAndReturnMax (array1=0x7fffffffdb30, len=5, max=44) at badprog.c:27
27              max = array1[i];
(gdb) print i
$3 = 4
(gdb) cont
Continuing.
max value in the array is 17
[Inferior 1 (process 690122) exited normally]
(gdb)
```

Comment: Happy debugging! The first thing I recommend to do though is to run the program through the [address and UB sanitizer](https://godbolt.org/z/dY9zc8Ec8). This easy step can save you hours of fiddling with gdb.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is my GDB executing two breakpoints at a time?

The debugger does not get to the breakpoint when `i` is 3 because `array[3]` is 2 and `max` at that time is 44, so `max < array1[i]` is false, and `if (max < array1[i])` skips the line where the breakpoint is, `max = array1[i];`.

> The values of i that are printed are 1,2,4 instead of 1,2,3,4,5.

Line 27 is inside the `if (max < array1[i])`, so the breakpoint there is only reached when `array1[i]` is greater than the current value of `max`.

When `i` is 1, `max` is 17 (because it was set from `array[0]`), and `array1[1]` is 22, so the breakpoint is reached. When you continue, `max` is updated to 22.

When `i` is 2, `max` is 22 (from above), and `array1[2]` is 44, so the breakpoint is reached. When you continue, `max` is updated to 44.

When `i` is 3, `max` is 44 (from above), and `array1[3]` is 2, so the program skips the “then” portion of the `if` and continues the loop. The breakpoint is not reached when `i` is 3 because the `max = array1[i];` statement was skipped.

When `i` is 4, `max` is 44 (from above), and `array1[4]` is 60, so the breakpoint is reached. When you continue, `max` is updated to 60.

When `i` is 5, `array1[5]` is out of bounds, and the behavior of the program is not defined by the C standard. It may be reading memory beyond the array. The condition `i <= len` in the `for` loop is wrong; you need `i < len` to limit the loop to valid indices for the array.

Additionally, the parameter `int max` declared in the function is a local copy of the argument value passed to it. Changing `max` in the `findAndReturnMax` function does not change the different object named `max` in the `main` routine. The function  needs to return the maximum in a different way, possibly by using `return max;` instead of `return 0;`. If it does that, there is no need for the `max` parameter in the function declaration. It would be a local variable declared inside the function instead.

Answer (score -4):

Your code has many issues. And those issues mess the emitted code "confusing" the gdb.

1. Undefined Behavior

```
    for (i=1; i <= len; i++) {
```

2. Your function always returns `0` (when you pass a not NULL pointer and positive `len`) and the compiler is optimizing out the whole code. It does not even need to call it as this function basically (except invoking an UB) does nothing.
3. `max` parameter is not needed. If you want to modify it you need to pass the reference to the function.
4. use the correct types for sizes and indexes.

```
/**
 * @brief Finds the maximum value in an integer array larger than `*max` and returns status.
 *
 * This function iterates through the given integer array and updates the provided
 * variable pointed to by 'max' with the maximum value found. The result of the operation
 * is indicated by the return value.
 *
 * @param array1 Pointer to the integer array to be searched.
 * @param len Size of the array.
 * @param max Pointer to the variable that will be updated with the maximum value found.
 *
 * @return
 * - 0: No valid maximum value .
 * - 1: Maximum value found and updated successfully in 'max'.
 * - -1: Invalid parameters
 */

int findAndReturnMax(const int *array1, const size_t len, int * const max) {

    size_t i;
    int result = -1;

    if (array1 && len )
    {
        result = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) 
        {
            if (*max < array1[i]) 
            {
                *max = array1[i];
                result = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int arr[5] = { 17, 21, 44, 2, 60 };

    int max = arr[0];

    switch ( findAndReturnMax(arr, 5, &max))
    {
        case -1:
            printf("BAD parameters\n");
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("max value in the array is %d\n", max);
            break;
        default:
            printf("No new max found\n");
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

PS I would rather not post any copyright messages in the code.

Comment: This code is from a textbook to teach how to use gdb. I wonder why for (i=1; i <= len; i++) is an undefined behavior？

Comment: @llcool because you access the array outside its bounds. when array1[5] is accessed UB is invoked. BTW the author of the textbook needs to learn C. I would not trust this textbook

Comment: @gulpr: No, the author of the textbook does not need to learn C. The program in the question is not intended to be a correct C program. It is from a lesson on debugging programs, not a lesson on C. As is documented in the program, it deliberately has errors, which the student is intended to examine with a debugger. And that is why this answer is completely off base. It does not explain OP’s observations in the debugger. It is written to tell OP what is wrong with “your code” (but it is not their code) but should say how to interpret the debugger output to understand the program and its errors.